# Delphi: hook ToggleSwitch manual State change to avoid a Click call

Tags: delphi, vcl

Delphi Rio 10.3.2

With the TToggleSwitch component, when you manually change the State property, i.e

```
ToggleSwitch1.State := tssOff
```

the OnClick event is called. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I would use an TAction connected to the TToggleSwitch and set its Checked property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few choices:

- set the `OnClick` property to `nil` before setting the `State`, then restore the event handler afterwards.

  ```pascal
  ToggleSwitch1.OnClick := nil;
  try
    ToggleSwitch1.State := ...;
  finally
    ToggleSwitch1.OnClick := ToggleSwitch1Click;
  end;
  ```
- set a flag before setting the `State`, then clear the flag afterwards, and have the `OnClick` event handler check the flag before doing anything.

  ```pascal
  ToggleSwitch1.Tag := 1;
  try
    ToggleSwitch1.State := ...;
  finally
    ToggleSwitch1.Tag := 0;
  end;

  procedure TMyForm.ToggleSwitch1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if ToggleSwitch1.Tag <> 0 then Exit;
    ...
  end;
  ```
- use an accessor class to reach the protected [`FClicksDisabled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TCustomToggleSwitch.FClicksDisabled) member so you can temporarily set it to True while changing the `State`:

  ```pascal
  type
    TToggleSwitchAccess = class(TToggleSwitch)
    end;

  TToggleSwitchAccess(ToggleSwitch1).FClicksDisabled := True;
  try
    ToggleSwitch1.State := ...;
  finally
    TToggleSwitchAccess(ToggleSwitch1).FClicksDisabled := False;
  end;
  ```

Comment: FWIW, controls like `TCheckBox` or `TRadioButton` behave the same - they fire `OnClick` when changing the value of `Checked` property. They both inherit from `TButtonControl` which has protected property [`ClicksDisabled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButtonControl.ClicksDisabled) to mute `OnClick`, but its description is slightly misleading. Similarly, `TToggleSwitch` has undocumented protected property `FClicksDisabled`.

Comment: @PeterWolf Good point. And [it is documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TCustomToggleSwitch.FClicksDisabled) actually, just not very well. But it does say "*This field is used internally during the toggle switch state changes*", at least.

Comment: D'oh! Of course it's documented. I was searching properties instead of fields ... But there's even more fun with events. `TEdit` [will fire OnChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014541/delphi-how-to-set-text-in-tedit-tmaskedit-without-invoking-the-onchange-event) when setting `Text` from code. `TComboBox`, on the other hand, [doesn't fire OnChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586597/altering-itemindex-of-tcombobox-does-not-trigger-its-onchange-event) nor `OnSelect` when changing its `Text` or `ItemIndex` and this is even documented behaviour.